# Drupal "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: drupal

I appreciate this question has been asked before but I couldn't find a quick fix to get my client's website live again - as it's been down all day. I have the "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." error on the website - I have a Drupal developer which normally helps with this but he is away.

Last time this error came up - I messaged him and he got it working in 30 seconds by "refreshing the site in cPanel" as he put it. Can someone tell me how I do this myself, as I can't access the Drupal admin but I can access cPanel, I just want to get the site live again.

Comment: "Unexpected error" doesn't say much. You'll have to check on some error logs to see the real reason. From my experience providers time to time change i.e. PHP version so some incompatible code stops working. So you can try with asking host company if they changed something recently. Good luck.

Comment: Were you able to find logs in cPanel for this, Ben?

Answer (score 0):

Your message is too vague and underlying cause must be found. It could be PHP related, twig error or event other.

This is not an answer as such but the only starting point to get deeper is to have more verbose output displayed, what drupal makes not as default.

Add following to your settings.php file and hopefully you will get a message giving a clue on what exactly to look after.

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

From there going further would be possible.

It may also be possible that your /admin/reports/dblog page is still accessible (depending on the real cause). If so, it may provide you with valuable info